# OOM when compression is enabled for Hive parquet tables

Tags: apache-spark

I have an ETL job that transforms Avro files into a Hive parquet table.

With compression enabled (snappy or gzip) the tasks will fail with OOM errors.

I map my Avro records and use the returned dataframe to insert into the Hive table like this

```
df.write.insertInto("default.results_parquet", overwrite=False)
```

Are there any special settings or things I should be aware of when enabling compression?

Comment: What's the number of partitions in the df? `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`?

Comment: There are 34 partitions

Comment: You may need to increase partitioning to better distribute the data. Can you try double for now, with `df.repartition(68).write.option("compression", "gzip").insertInto("default.results_parquet", overwrite=False)`

Comment: It worked when I bumped it up to 200. I now end up with hundreds of parquet files that are ~5 MB in size. It seems like a bad trade-off for compression.

Comment: What's the schema of the Avro records? Is it highly nested? You should not need 200 partitions. How much memory do your executors have?

Comment: The avro schema is flat, a few ints and one large string ½-1 MB in size. Each executor has 32 GB of mem, of which I assign 20GB